# How to solve this system of 3 ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I would like to know how to solve this system of differential equation.
[image]

It consist of 3 ODEs, describing the behavior of an Induction Machine supplied with DC voltage.
I a interested to derive the input current to the machine(I1) but not numerically.
In Matlab i could find the numerical solution and could plot the curve(Transferring to Laplace, solving equation and then doing inverse Laplace), but i need the answer to be a mathematics expression. I believe the answer should contain an exponential term+some hyperbolic term.

Laplace transform:(Maybe i don't really need to solve it through conversion to Laplace, because finding the inverse Laplace is very difficult)

[image]

Matlab output waveform:

[image]

Circuit:
[image]

clear;

syms r1 l1 r2 l2 rc lm real;
syms i1(t) i2(t) i3(t) s;
di1(t) = diff(i1(t),t);
di2(t) = diff(i2(t),t);
di3(t) = diff(i3(t),t);

E = 1;  % Voltage
eq1(t) = di1(t) + ((rc+r1)/l1)*i1(t) - (rc/l1)*i2(t)-E/l1;
eq2(t) = di2(t) - di3(t) + (rc/lm)*i2(t) - (rc/lm)*i1(t);
eq3(t) = di3(t) - (lm/(lm+l2))* di2(t) + (r2/(lm+l2))*i3(t);

L1(t) = laplace(eq1,t,s);
L2(t) = laplace(eq2,t,s);
L3(t) = laplace(eq3,t,s);
%{0.3,0.2,100,0.1,0.00386,0.004,0,0,0});

syms Li1 Li2 Li3
% Ni1=L1(t);
% Ni2=L2(t);
% Ni3=L3(t);

Ni1 = subs(L1(t),{r1,r2,rc,lm,l1,l2,i1(0),i2(0),i3(0)}, ...
      {0.3,0.2,100,0.1,0.00386,0.004,0,0,0});

Ni2 = subs(L2(t),{r1,r2,rc,lm,l1,l2,i1(0),i2(0),i3(0)}, ...
      {0.3,0.2,100,0.1,0.00386,0.004,0,0,0});

Ni3 = subs(L3(t),{r1,r2,rc,lm,l1,l2,i1(0),i2(0),i3(0)}, ...
      {0.3,0.2,100,0.1,0.00386,0.004,0,0,0});

Ni1 =...
subs(Ni1,{laplace(i1(t),t,s),laplace(i2(t),t,s),laplace(i3(t),t,s)},{Li1,Li2,Li3});
NI1 = collect(Ni1,Li1)

Ni2 = ...
subs(Ni2,{laplace(i1(t),t,s), laplace(i2(t),t,s),laplace(i3(t),t,s)}, {Li1,Li2,Li3});

Ni2 = collect(Ni2,Li2);

Ni3 = ...
subs(Ni3,{laplace(i1(t),t,s), laplace(i2(t),t,s),laplace(i3(t),t,s)}, {Li1,Li2,Li3});

Ni3 = collect(Ni3,Li2);

[Li1, Li2, Li3] = solve(Ni1, Ni2, Ni3, Li1, Li2, Li3)

i1 = ilaplace(Li1, s, t);
i2 = ilaplace(Li2, s, t);
i3 = ilaplace(Li3, s, t);

simplify(i1);
simplify(i2);
simplify(i3);

i1=vpa(i1)
i2=vpa(i2)
i3=vpa(i3)

Di1=diff(i1);
Ll1=E./Di1;
Lxpll2=(diff(Di1));

t=0:1e-4:10;
Ii1=subs(i1,t);
DDi1=subs(Di1,t);
LLl1=subs(Ll1,t);
LLxpll2=subs(Lxpll2,t);

% i1=vpa(i1)
% i2=vpa(i2)

% 
% % 
 subplot(2,2,1); plot(t,Ii1);
 title('Input current'); ylabel('i1(t)[A]'); xlabel('t[s]');grid
 subplot(2,2,2); plot(t,DDi1);
 title('Derivation of the current: di1(t)/d(t)'); ylabel('di1(t)/d(t)');xlabel('t[s]'); grid
 subplot(2,2,3); plot(t,LLl1);
 title('Input inductance'); ylabel('Li[H]');xlabel('t[s]'); grid
  subplot(2,2,4); plot(t,LLxpll2);
 title('Second derivation of the current: d^2i1(t)/d(t)'); ylabel('d^2i1(t)/d(t)');xlabel('t[s]'); grid

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Yes, i do have the component values, but the thing is i want to solve it by parametric values, to be able to analyses the behaviour of the input current based on the parameters value. If i replace parameters with values, i would have no idea how does it behave based on changes in parameters.

Comment: You mean replace params with war(e.g. let a=(rc+rl)/L1.) and then using the laplace approach?

Comment: You can use the Laplace transform to compute $t \mapsto e^{At}$, and this will give the general solution as $x(t) = e^{At} x_0 + \int_0^t e^{A(t-\tau)} B d \tau $ for appropriate $A,b$. It is a little messy.

Comment: i did laplace transform and then inverse laplace in matlab, i got a very big statement, is there any way to solve by hand with a hope to make it simpler?

Comment: Actually, to do what I suggested, you may need to pick different state variables (or some linear combination of existing).

Comment: i_s =
 
(a*s^2 + b*s + c)/(d*s^4 + e*s^3 + f*s^2 + g*s)

Comment: I got:   i=c/g - (c*d*sum((r6^2*exp(r6*t))/(3*d*r6^2 + 2*e*r6 + f), r6 in RootOf(d*s6^3 + e*s6^2 + f*s6 + g, s6)) - b*g*sum(exp(r6*t)/(3*d*r6^2 + 2*e*r6 + f), r6 in RootOf(d*s6^3 + e*s6^2 + f*s6 + g, s6)) + c*f*sum(exp(r6*t)/(3*d*r6^2 + 2*e*r6 + f), r6 in RootOf(d*s6^3 + e*s6^2 + f*s6 + g, s6)) - a*g*sum((r6*exp(r6*t))/(3*d*r6^2 + 2*e*r6 + f), r6 in RootOf(d*s6^3 + e*s6^2 + f*s6 + g, s6)) + c*e*sum((r6*exp(r6*t))/(3*d*r6^2 + 2*e*r6 + f), r6 in RootOf(d*s6^3 + e*s6^2 + f*s6 + g, s6)))/g

Comment: It is hard to read, but broadly looks like what I might expect. I don't think there is a reason to expect that the denominator factors conveniently.

Comment: Is there any other way rather than using Matlab to solve it, because this output is catastrophic!

Comment: Well, unless you can symbolically factor the characteristic equation, I don't seen anything cleaner?

Comment: Actually the equaation for I1 in laplace is: 
 
i1_s = (a*s^2 + b*s + c)/(d*s^4 + e*s^3 + f*s^2 + g*s)   i can not make it more clean, for the solution however (The big statement that is the Laplace inverse of this clean expression) it really is difficult to make it clean.

Comment: if you want to know, when i put a=b=c=d=e=f=g=1, i get very nice result :    I1_t= c + sin(t) - (c*cos(t))/2 - (c*sin(t))/2 - (c*exp(-t))/2

Comment: Some prof at university suggest me to use Maple or Mathematica instead of matlab, what do you think?

Comment: I don't know really, I only use Maxima when I need such things. I'm not sure this is an issue with the particular symbolic package.

Comment: When you take your Laplace transform, your emf term $E/L_1$ somehow turns into $E/(sL_1)$. Can you clarify that? (It would really help if you turned both of those images into Mathjax, in fact...)

Comment: Different software works differently. It's a good idea to understand how one works and how to fully use it in a given situation or you may not get any answer from any of them (assuming there is one). I'm not clear on what you're doing in Matlab -an edited question with code would be helpful. Are you using the [Symbolic Math toolbox](http://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/) and [`dsolve`](http://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/dsolve.html) in Matlab? Have you applied any [assumptions](http://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assume.html) to your symbolic variables in Matlab?

Comment: For a constant value c, the laplace transform is C/s,

Comment: I uploaded the code in the question. I am also going to try Mathematica.

Answer (score 0):

You have a series circuit of three things to which a signal is applied.
$$
         R1+L1+(RC || Lm || (R2+L2)),
$$
where I am using $||$ to indicate parallel. This one circuit gives the main equation. Then you figure out how to look at any one of the three series items in this through a divider, and then burrow down into the parallel currents if needed.

**More detail**: I'm using your Laplace transform equations:
$$
\begin{array}{llll}
    (sL_1+R_1)I_1  & +R_c(I_1-I_2) & & = E/s \\
     & +R_c(I_2-I_1) & +sL_m(I_2-I_3) & = 0 \\
     & & +sL_m(I_3-I_2) +(sL_2+R_2)I_3 & = 0
\end{array}
$$
Add these three equations to relate $I_1$ to $I_3$:
$$
   (sL_1+R_1)I_1 +(sL_2+R_2)I_3  = E/s,\\
       I_3 = \frac{E/s-(sL_1+R_1)I_1}{sL_2+R_2}.
$$
Use this to relate $I_2$ to $I_1$ using the second loop equation:
$$
\begin{align}
       (R_c +sL_m) I_2 & = R_c I_1+sL_m I_3 \\
          & =R_c I_1 + sL_m\frac{E/s-(sL_1+R_1)I_1}{sL_2+R_2}\\
          & =\left[R_c-\frac{sL_m(sL_1+R_1)}{sL_2+R_2}\right]I_1+\frac{L_m}{sL_2+R_2}E
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
    I_2 = \frac{1}{sL_m+R_c}\left[\left[R_c-\frac{sL_m(sL_1+R_1)}{sL_2+R_2}\right]I_1+\frac{L_m}{sL_2+R_2}E\right]\\
  = \frac{R_c(sL_2+R_2)-sL_m(sL_1+R_1)}{(sL_m+R_c)(sL_2+R_2)}I_1
    +\frac{L_m}{(sL_m+R_c)(sL_2+R_2)}E\\
  = -\frac{L_m L_1 s^{2}+(L_m R_1-L_2 R_c)s-R_c R_2}{(sL_m+R_c)(sL_2+R_2)}I_1
    +\frac{L_m}{(sL_m+R_c)(sL_2+R_2)}E
$$
Rewrite the first loop equation
$$
       (sL_1+R_1+R_c)I_1 = R_c I_2 +E/s \\
       I_1 = \frac{R_c}{sL_1+R_1+R_c}I_2+\frac{E}{s(sL_1+R_1+R_c)} \\
    = -\frac{L_m L_1 s^{2}+(L_m R_1-L_2 R_c)s-R_c R_2}{(sL_m+R_c)(sL_2+R_2)(sL_1+R_1+R_2)}R_cI_1\\
  - \frac{1}{(sL_m+R_c)(sL_2+R_2)(sL_1+R_1+R_2)}R_cL_mE \\
  + \frac{E}{s(sL_1+R_1+R_c)}
$$
Now you have $I_1$ in terms of $E$.
$$
    \left[1+\frac{L_m L_1 s^{2}+(L_m R_1-L_2 R_c)s-R_c R_2}{(sL_m+R_c)(sL_2+R_2)(sL_1+R_1+R_2)}R_c\right]I_1  \\
 = \left[-\frac{R_cL_m}{(sL_m+R_c)(sL_2+R_2)(sL_1+R_1+R_2)}
   +\frac{1}{s(sL_1+R_1+R_c)}\right]E
$$
Multiplying both sides by $(sL_m+R_c)(sL_2+R_2)(sL_1+R_1+R_2)$, simplifying the cubic coefficient $C(s)$ of $I_1$ and dividing by that coefficient gives $I_1 = \frac{1}{C(s)}\frac{p(s)}{s}E$, where $p$ is a cubic function polynomial. There are explicit solutions for the roots of a cubic. So, you can explicitly find the inverse Laplace transform after factoring $C(s)$ by using the inverse Laplace transform integral and the calculus of residues.

Comment: But the problem is, you are not allowed to change the ciruit to the equivalent ircuit, since it is operating in DC transient rather than ac continous signal.

Comment: @Hesam : But the idea is still the same. You can get one equation in $I_{1}$ and derive $I_{2}$, $I_{3}$. I'll post more and show you how to solve the Laplace transform equation. The post will take a bit to appear because I'll be working on it.

Comment: OK, really app reiate it thnaks